# Crystal reports page break inside text object

Tags: crystal-reports

Is it possible to put a page break inside a text object?

I have a report that has two separate text objects that are hidden under mutually exclusive conditions. The report needs to be called from the same event which lead to this design.

The objects are different lengths. I have placed one on top of the other, and the display works well. The issue is that the longer one, which breaks onto two pages, needs to break at a specific point. The shorter object fits on a page, but is longer than the first page of the other object. The detail section is set to grow.

If I could drop a hard page break inside the text object, all would be well. I have not been able to find this functionality. I am new to Crystal, so be kind...

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly could you try this?
In design view right click on the details section at the far left and select insert section below. Do this twice and you will now have three detail sections.
In the first section place your smaller text object.
In the second one create a formula that limits the size of your longer text object to the size you need. Something like

```
left({@test1},500- instr(trim(StrReverse (left({@test1},500)))," "))
```

in the third

```
mid({@test1},(501- instr(trim(StrReverse (left({@test1},500)))," "))+1,1000)
```

NOTE: 500 would be the approximate break point. The rest of the formula insures you break at a space and not in the middle of a word. 1000 (less 500 apprx) is the max length of the text in C. Both of those can be changed along with the suppression formulas referred to below to accommodate your data.. replace {@test1} with the field or formula that contains your text.

Use your current suppression formulas to suppress SECTION detail a and SECTION detail (b and c)
add a page break formula to b if the length of that formula is greater than 500

add suppression to c if the length of {@test1} is less than 501.

I just tested this on a 2000 word text string and it seems to work fine

Comment: That is ingenious, but unfortunately my text object is not of fixed length. There are fields in each that make the objects non-static. I might be able to adapt this approach by using the length of the fields. I'm stuck in a meeting right now so I can't try it right away. I'll let you know how it turns out!

Comment: What do you mean by your text object? Are you referring to a field from your database? Or a formula made up of different fields?

Comment: I have a text object that references fields inside. I'm actually noticing that in the long one the only ones referenced are dates which I can format to have the same length. I will able to try this when I get out of this meeting. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I was able to solve this with just two detail sections and some moving around of the longer text object. Thanks, CoSpringsGuy! Your help was instrumental.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this with just two detail sections, applying Suppress Blank Section and Suppress (No Drill-Down) with the suppress logic of the text objects, and some moving around of the longer text object. Thanks, CoSpringsGuy! Your help was instrumental.